# About a result on Hadamard matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

I am currently reading "On Subsets with Cardinalities of Intersections Divisible by a Fixed Integer" by P. Frankl And A. M. Odlyzko. They used the following result without citation:

For each number $l$, we have a decomposition $l=l_1+\cdots+l_q$ with $l_i\geq\epsilon l$ for a fixed constant $\epsilon$, such that the Hadamard matrix of size $4l_k$ exists.

Would anyone provide a reference or a short proof that I missed? THX

Comment: I thought Hadamard matrices existed for each size $4n$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, that is the Hadamard Conjecture, widely believed but open

Comment: The paper actually says $l$ is  even, you should transcribe more carefully

Comment: Is there supposed to be a "for all $k$, $1\le k\le q$"?

Comment: It should follow from some version of Goldbach (since there exist Hadamard matrices of order $2(p+1)$ for all odd prime $p$, this follows from Goldbach with many summands but additional condition that they are all of comparable size.)

Comment: @kodlu I read that paper again and don't think the author implies that $l$ is even. The first sentence should be understood as '... for large $n$ and $l$ (even without) ...' Otherwise, it's a little bit tricky if '... for (large $n$) and ($l$ even) without...' In addition, the introduction part of 'Two Remarks on Eventown and Oddtown Problems' by Sudakov referring to this paper regards $l$ as an arbitrary number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, omitted it due to my laziness and possibly no misunderstanding.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think you are in the right direction. And the construction is named after Paley. Me a noob in (all kinds of) number theory, thus unable to proceed any further and struggling to find related papers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be proved using the strategy of Fedor Petrov and a theorem from the following paper:

*Haselgrove, C. B.*, [**Some theorems in the analytic theory of numbers**](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-26.4.273), J. Lond. Math. Soc. 26, 273-277 (1951). [ZBL0043.04704](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0043.04704).

Let $63/64 < \theta < 1$.
According to Theorem A of Hasselgrove, if $m$ is a sufficiently large odd number, then $m$ is the sum of three primes $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ with $|p_i-m/3| < m^{\theta}$. Putting $m = 2 \ell-3$, we obtain
$$4 \ell = 2(p_1+1) + 2(p_2+1) + 2(p_3+1).$$

The [Paley construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) gives a Hadamard matrix of size $2(p+1)$ for any odd prime $p$. Since $p_i = (1/3) m + O(m^{\theta})$, we have $2(p_i+1) = (4/3) \ell + O(\ell^{\theta})$.

The exponent $63/64$ has been improved on by many other authors; for example, [Matomakai, Maynard and Shao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02017) push it down to $11/20$. But the OP just asked for each of the matrix sizes to be comparable to $\ell$, so I'll stop here.

Comment: A few weeks ago I was at the talk of Mark Rudelson, and he and Xiaoyu Dong [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.07523) actually used this same idea to construct almost Hadamar matrices of all sizes (including the case $n$ not divisible by $4$).

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Thanks! The relevant work seems to be Section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.07523 .

Comment: Ah, and Dong and Rudelson's result is nicer, in that they get almost Hadamard matrices with entries in $\{ -1, 1 \}$, rather than $\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$.